# Creating a char array using hex values

Tags: c, hex, arrays

I've got a quick question to someone that knows their way around C - I'm trying to save a char array using hex values, so it looks like this :

```
char string[84]={0x32,0x51,0x0b,0xa9,0xba,0xbe,0xbb,0xbe,0xfd,0x00,0x15,0x47,0xa8,0x10,0xe6,0x71,0x49,0xca,0xee,0x11,0xd9,0x45,0xcd,0x7f,0xc8,0x1a,0x05,0xe9,0xf8,0x5a,0xac,0x65,0x0e,0x90,0x52,0xba,0x6a,0x8c,0xd8,0x25,0x7b,0xf1,0x4d,0x13,0xe6,0xf0,0xa8,0x03,0xb5,0x4f,0xde,0x9e,0x77,0x47,0x2d,0xbf,0xf8,0x9d,0x71,0xb5,0x7b,0xdd,0xef,0x12,0x13,0x36,0xcb,0x85,0xcc,0xb8,0xf3,0x31,0x5f,0x4b,0x52,0xe3,0x01,0xd1,0x6e,0x9f,0x52,0xf9,0x04};
```

so basically when I output it using for example something like

```
for (i=0;i<string_len;i++)
        printf("%d \t---\t %x\n",i,cipher_11[i]);
```

I'd expect to get the same values, just without the 0x in front and it does work for most of those values, some of them however have "ffff" in front which kind of breaks the rest of my program :) Kind of a newbie in hex operations so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something very silly. Any hints ? (btw the output looks like the picture : http://postimg.org/image/k0npwh9a5/ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of your characters have their most significant bit set, and so would represent a negative value (assuming your compiler treats `char` as a signed value).  So when it is implicitly cast as an integer (during the call to `printf`), it will be interpreted as a negative value.  This is the case for all values larger than `0x7f`.

You should either declare `cipher_11` as `unsigned char`, or cast the value during `printf`:

```
printf("%d \t---\t %x\n", i, (unsigned char)cipher_11[i]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply, that does solve the issue :). I was thinking it might have something to do with negative numbers, just wasn't sure how to get around that. declaring the value as unsigned char does exactly what I want - in dev c++ at least :).